# How to add new line in file in bash?

Tags: shell, unix, awk

my input file contains

```
<arg>arg1</arg>
<arg>arg2</arg>
<arg>arg3</arg>
<arg>arg4</arg>
```

now i want to add new line `<arg>arg5</arg>`.
I used below command
`awk '{gsub("<arg>arg4</arg>", "<arg>arg4</arg>\n<arg>arg5</arg>", $0); print}' inputfile > tempfile`

But its not working at all. Its also not giving any errors.
Please help me out here.

Comment: If you are appending lines to the end of a file, neither `awk` nor `sed` is the appropriate tool.  Use `echo`, `printf`, or `cat`.  eg `echo '<arg>arg5</arg>' >> input-file`

Comment: or `{ cat input-file; echo '<arg>arg5</arg>'; } > output-file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple string comparison to avoid escaping of special characters like `$`, `(` and `)` in regular expressions:

```
awk '1
  $0 == "<arg>arg4</arg>"{
    print "<arg>arg5</arg>"
  }
' inputfile > tempfile
```

The first `1` prints the current line and if the current line is `<arg>arg4</arg>`, print
`<arg>arg5</arg>`.

If the search string is only part of the line (padded by whitespace for example), you could use `index` to get the position of the search string
and insert the new string after it:

```
# define two shell variables
search='<arg>arg4</arg>'
insert='<arg>arg5</arg>'

awk -v search="$search" -v insert="$insert" '
{
  idx=index($0, search)
  if (idx){
    print substr($0, 1, idx+length(search)-1) ORS insert substr($0, idx+length(search))
    next
  }
}1' inputfile > tempfile
```

The long `print` statement prints the following parts

- the string *before* the `search` string + the `search` string itself
- a newline
- the `insert` string
- the string *after* the `search` string (possibly empty)

Answer (score 0):

One way using sed:
File1:

```
$ cat file1
<arg>arg1</arg>
<arg>arg2</arg>
<arg>arg3</arg>
<arg>arg4</arg>
```

File2:

```
$ cat file2
<arg>arg5</arg>
```

sed command:

```
$ sed -i '$r file2' file1
```

Check file1:

```
$ cat file1
<arg>arg1</arg>
<arg>arg2</arg>
<arg>arg3</arg>
<arg>arg4</arg>
<arg>arg5</arg>
```

Using sed, we can simply read the contents of another file into current file. 
`$r file2`- read(`r`) when the last line(`$`) is read. `-i` to edit the file in-place.